# Erro em função anonima não permite compilar

Tags: php, php-7, função-anônima

Estou estudando um livro PHP OO. Tem um exemplo de função anônima, porém está dando erro:

```
# FUNÇÂO ANONIMA
$remove_acento = function($str) {
$a = array(
    'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó',
    'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Ç', 'È', 'É',
    'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý'
);
$b = array(
    'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o',
    'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'E',
    'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y'
);
return str_replace($a, $b, $str);
}

print $remove_acento('José da Conceição');
```

Ao ser executada, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'print' (T_PRINT)

Não vejo erro direto nesse código. Uso PHP 7.0.8.

Comment: Acho curioso um livro de OOP ensinando usar função anônima :D Eu falo que o pessoal usa o termo só por marketing...

Comment: Falta um `;` antes do `print`: `$remove_acento = function($str) { };`.

Comment: @bigown Por curiosidade, você deu uma resposta e em seguida fechou a pergunta como um erro de digitação. Existe algum motivo para essa situação ter ocorrido?

Comment: @stderr Porque é só um erro de digitação, precisa de uma resposta para ser finalizada, mas não vai atender mais ninguém (antigamente se fechava como *too specific*). O padrão é fazer isso, o motivo de fechamento existe justamente pra esses casos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está faltando um `;` no final da declaração da variável:

```
$remove_acento = function($str) {
    $a = array(
        'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó',
        'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Ç', 'È', 'É',
        'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý'
    );
    $b = array(
        'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o',
        'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'E',
        'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y'
    );
    return str_replace($a, $b, $str);
};

print $remove_acento('José da Conceição');
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2XDNbi). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/elnxmzkv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/ChangeDiacritic.php).